# Evaluate Column Not in Group By

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to somehow evaluate a column called GL when it is not in the GROUP BY statement using Oracle 12c. I don't want to include it in GROUP BY because it will output a row for each different number in GL. However, I need to be able to tell if a list of GLs is in the output.

These are sample tables containing the GLs I need to compare against the results:

```
select asset_appv_acct, purch_accts, legal_accts
  from ap_settings
```

Sample contents of each:

```
ASSET_APPV_ACCT:17101,17102,17112,17151,17161,52602,52467,18005,18010,18011,18014,18015,18041,18042,18043,18044,18045,18046,18047,18048,18049,18050,18052,18053,18054,18055,18056,18057,18058,18059,18060
PURCH_ACCTS: 52402,52407,52460,52639
LEGAL_ACCTS: 52608,52615,52616,52617,52618,52621,52626,52635,52636,52659,52662,52663,52664,52680,52682,52683,52684,52685
```

Here's a sample of the query:

```
SELECT h.h_spa_id as spa_id,h.submit_dt,h.oa_ap_date,SomeAggregateFunction()
  FROM table1 h,table2 d, table3
  WHERE h.next_apprv= 'approverID'
    and h.table1_id = d.table2_id
    and h.table1_id = table3_id
  group by h.h_spa_id,h.submit_dt,h.oa_ap_date
  order by h.h_spa_id
```

And here's an example of the result:

```
1627005 1/25/2008 10:11:53 AM 1/25/2008 11:15:56 AM (Result of Aggregate Function Here)
```

I'd like to evaluate the list above, fed in dynamically from a sub-query or something, and output an indicator field. For example, outputting a 1 if the GL is in the list and a 0 if it is not.

The trick is that I need to check the GL field in table2 but not include it in the GROUP BY clause.

Note: I tried CASE and DECODE. DECODE was not comparing the items in the list, just the entire list. So I was always getting the 'no match' scenario. CASE seems unwieldy because I'd have to extract each GL separately from the list and create a new case for syntax's sake, like

```
WHEN '18327' THEN '*'
WHEN '52407' THEN '*'
WHEN '52460' THEN '*'
```

What is the easy way to query those lists as part of the same result set and evaluate the GLs?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. You want to compare the `spa_id` (which you are grouping on) with any value from any of those three columns in `ap_settings`, and add a 0/1 flag to each row in your result set? And your example output row would get 0 because 1627005 isn't in the other table? Why can't that be in the group-by, as it will be the same flag value for all rows for a `spa_id`?

Comment: You got a comma-delimited list in a column (ouch) and want to check if a specific value exists within that list? Use a `REGEXP_SIMILAR` over a `MIN(GL)`

Comment: I want to compare GL to any value from those 3 columns in ap_settings, then output it as a flag value column 0/1 apart from GROUP BY.

Comment: I think my previous comment was wrong then; you aren't comparing `spa_id` with anything, you're comparing `table2.gl` with the values in `ap_settings`, and you can have multiple `table2.gl` values for each `spa_id`, and don't want to show the actual `gl` value at all? (Does your `ap_settings` table have comma-separated values, or have you just listed them like that in the question and each value is actually in a separate row?)

Comment: You still didn't answer if it a single column with a comma-delimited list of values or is there a row for each value? And what's the datatype of `GL`, numeric or varchar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're doing, you can left-join to your look-up table to see if the GL value exists in any of those columns, which will give you a 0/1 flag for each row; and then aggregate that with `max()`. If *any* GL for the rows you are grouping by does have a match then you'll get a 1, otherwise you'll just get 0.

Something like:

```
SELECT h.h_spa_id as spa_id,h.submit_dt,h.oa_ap_date,SomeAggregateFunction(),
         max(case when ap.gl is null then 0 else 1 end) as flag
FROM table1 h
JOIN table2 d
ON d.table2_id = h.table1_id
JOIN table3
ON table3_id = h.table1_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT asset_appv_acct AS gl
  FROM ap_settings
  UNION
  SELECT purch_accts
  FROM ap_settings
  UNION
  SELECT legal_accts
  FROM ap_settings
) ap
ON ap.gl = d.gl
WHERE h.next_apprv= 'approverID'
GROUP BY h.h_spa_id,h.submit_dt,h.oa_ap_date
ORDER BY h.h_spa_id
```

I've switched to 'modern' join syntax because it's generally easier anyway, but much simpler for outer joins.

I've also joined to a union of the three columns from the look-up table, rather than joining to three copies of the table, to make the case statement simpler.

I'm *assuming* that what you've shown is a list of values from separate rows, but the different number of values suggests maybe you have a comma-separated string in one column - which is a horrible design. If that is the case then you'll need change the subquery to tokenize the values; or you can use a regular expression search for each individual `table2.gl` value from each of the three strings, but that will probably be slower and more expensive (as it has to be done for every value) than tokenizing the whole lot once.

From comments it turns out you do have comma-separated lists, not only in the `ap_settings` table, but in the `table2.gl` column too. That makes it messy. You need to tokenize both, something like:

---

```
SELECT h.h_spa_id as spa_id,h.submit_dt,h.oa_ap_date,SomeAggregateFunction(),
         max(case when ap.gl is null then 0 else 1 end) as flag
FROM table1 h
JOIN (
  SELECT table2_id, regexp_substr(gl, '[^,]+', 1, level) AS gl
  FROM table2
  CONNECT BY regexp_substr(gl, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
  AND PRIOR table2_id = table2_id
  AND PRIOR dbms_random.value IS NOT NULL
) d
ON d.table2_id = h.table1_id
JOIN table3
ON table3_id = h.table1_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT regexp_substr(asset_appv_acct, '[^,]+', 1, level) AS gl
  FROM ap_settings
  CONNECT BY regexp_substr(asset_appv_acct, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
  UNION
  SELECT regexp_substr(purch_accts, '[^,]+', 1, level) AS gl
  FROM ap_settings
  CONNECT BY regexp_substr(purch_accts, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
  UNION
  SELECT regexp_substr(legal_accts, '[^,]+', 1, level) AS gl
  FROM ap_settings
  CONNECT BY regexp_substr(legal_accts, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
) ap
ON ap.gl = d.gl
WHERE h.next_apprv= 'approverID'
GROUP BY h.h_spa_id,h.submit_dt,h.oa_ap_date
ORDER BY h.h_spa_id;
```

But you now have multiple rows, so you'll need to look carefully at what `SomeAggregateFunction()` is actually doing, so it gets the right result...

Comment: OK, I see how UNION ALL will be a BIG help. I'm getting a flag of 0 on GL 52603 even though it's in the list when I run the UNION ALL queries separately. Also, when we join on ap.gl = d.gl does that mean it will only return rows when d.gl matches ap rows? Or is that just the statement to link the rows?In my web page, will be outputting all SPAs but indicating which SPAs are in the list. So I need to output them whether them match the 'special' GLs or not...Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @Allen - the `on ap.gl = d.gl` would mean it only returned rows that matched if it was an inner join; that's why I made it a left outer join. For the rows that don't match, you'll still get all the data from the other tables, and `ap.gl` will be null - which is what the case statement is checking for. If it's null, there was no match, therefore use zero.

Comment: With some made-up data this seems to work; you don't have 52603 in the sample data but obviously I can't see what you really have. Also I changed it from UNION ALL to UNION to suppress duplicates - in case the same value can appear multiple times, in one or more columns, which could throw out your current aggregate result. It wouldn't matter for min/max/avg, but would for count.

Comment: Isn't it comparing the GL in a single row of table2 to the entire list of ap.gl? I'm still getting all flags with 0.

Comment: @Allen - it's seeing if there is a match between the table2.gl to any ap.gl. Which should be at most one, since they are now distinct (from the union suppressing duplicates). What are the data types of all the columns involved? If they're numbers I'm not sure how you aren't getting matches.

Comment: The fields all have comma separated lists in them, like:  GL  ROW1: 23423,29383,39382  ROW2: 39283,28393,85848  ROW3: 28389,38291,32223

Comment: Oh, wow. That is... such a bad design. You'll need to tokenize the ap_settings values (as I mentioned already) if they are also comma-separated; and also tokenize the GL values. And them compare the values in both tokenized lists. At the moment the flag will only get 1 if the *entire* GL values matches an entire row from the ap_settings, which is - I assume - unlikely.

Comment: @Allen - updated with a demo of that kind of approach, but you need to be careful with your aggregate function. Good luck.

Comment: This seems to output a table with an 'index' of 'level' and each number in the list as a row...SELECT regexp_substr (asset_appv_acct, '[^,]+', 1, level), level
FROM ap_settings
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(regexp_replace (asset_appv_acct, '[^,]+'));

Comment: @Allen - yes, that's a variation of what I used; you can use `regexp_count` in the connect-by clause too. All the same basic idea. For `table2.gl` I've included two `prior` checks to stop it cycling or mixing values from different rows; not clear if you need to do the same with the `ap_settings` data, don't know if there are multiple rows, and if so if there's any connection from a particular row to the other tables.

Comment: No, there is only one row. The code is humming along. Thanks again for your help.